# Browser shows IPv6, yet query returns IPv4 -- why?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ipv6, ipv4

A bit of context: For study/practice, I'm working on a network application and I noticed that the socket only correctly opens if I provide an IPv4 address to people whose public IP is IPv4 and IPv6 for those whose public IP is IPv6.

I thought to select filter the right one by using something kindred to the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException { 
        BufferedReader ipTypeChecker = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                new URL("https://wtfismyip.com/text").openStream()
            )
        );

        System.out.println(ipTypeChecker.readLine());
    }
}
```

If I simply google What is my ip, go to [this page](https://wtfismyip.com/text) or [this page](http://myexternalip.com/raw), My IP is shown as an IPv6 address, yet if I query those pages using the above code it returns an IPv4 address, why?

Of course, if I am suffering from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) feel free to point out where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Don't try to second guess the network architecture. Lots of systems have both IPv4 and IPv6, or are behind a NAT64 gateway, or ... etc ... Make your application behave nicely in any environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) Java prefers IPv4 addresses to IPv6 addresses if both are available:

> java.net.preferIPv6Addresses (default: false)
>
> If IPv6 is available on the operating system the default preference is to prefer an IPv4-mapped address over an IPv6 address. This is for backward compatibility reasons...

The target host has both types of address:

```
wtfismyip.com.          3600    IN      AAAA    2604:4300:a:2c::1:1
wtfismyip.com.          3600    IN      A       69.30.217.90
```

This means Java will pick the IPv4 address. Browsers will instead prefer IPv6 usually.